# Is this tcp listener code implemented correctly regarding ResetEvents and Threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, windows-services

I have this code that I don't feel is working as well as it should.  I've pieced it together and it works, but I don't fully understand Async threads and the ResetEvents.

When I test this listener with a multi-threaded client sending 100 connections in the response time goes from 300 milliseconds for the first 10 or so up to 2-3 seconds for the last 50.

1.)  Is the threading and the resetevent handlers implemented as they were designed to do?

2.)  Is there some way to speed up the response time of high traffic bursts?

3.)  Would it make sense to run the tcpConnectionLogic on another thread?

I have a manual and auto reset event globally scoped:

```
   private AutoResetEvent connectionWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
   private ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

I have a windows service which starts a tcp listener on a new thread

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _mainThread = new Thread(ThreadListener_Begin);

    _mainThread.Name = "EMServiceThread";
    _mainThread.IsBackground = false;
    _mainThread.Start();
}
```

My thread runs a loop waiting for the manual resent event to signal a shutdown.

```
private void ThreadListener_Begin()
{
    TcpListener listener = null;
    listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.30.248"), 10010);

    listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
    listener.Start();

        while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
        {
            IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, listener);
            connectionWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
}
```

Finally when a connection comes in I accept it and pass it off to a type of logic layer which processes the requests.

```
private void HandleAsyncConnection(IAsyncResult result)
{ 
  TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;

  connectionWaitHandle.Set();

  TcpClient c = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);

  var _tcpConnectedLogic = new TcpConnectionLogic(c);

  _tcpConnectedLogic.BadRequestAlert += _serviceLogic_BadRequestAlert;
  _tcpConnectedLogic.RequestDecodedAlert += _tcpConnectedLogic_RequestDecodedAlert;
  _tcpConnectedLogic.Start();

    }
```

**EDIT**
When I stop my service my thread does not close as I expect it to.  Rather it end's up aborting.  Why?  How can I make it close gracefully?

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    WriteToEventLog("Stop Command Received" + CurrentTimeStamp, entryType: EventLogEntryType.Information);
    WriteToLogFile("Stop Command Received @ " + CurrentTimeStamp);
    _shutdownEvent.Set();

    if (!_mainThread.Join(4000))
    {
        WriteToEventLog("OnStop: Aborting thread, Join did not work.  This is not preferred.", entryType: EventLogEntryType.Warning);
        _mainThread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you fine with using async\await?

Comment: The response time problems must come from code not visible here. Post the request processing code.

Comment: @usr are you suggesting that the code I have shown is correctly implemented?

Comment: It has quality issues (see the answer) but it should not exhibit that particular behavior (high latency).

Comment: I'm confused because the connectionWaitHandle.WaitOne() is from the Microsoft examples and comes with the basic implementation of their Azure extension and cloud worker role project type.

Comment: The MSDN example are an abomination. See the answer for why this makes no sense. It is not hard to understand. The guy who wrote the MSDN socket code had no clue what he did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this block

```
while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
{
    IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, listener);
    connectionWaitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

You are basically accepting clients in a loop, because you are blocking thread by waiting on connectionWaitHandle. You could as well forget about async stuff and just do:

```
while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
{                
     var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
     // start your logic in separate thread                
}
```

I don't say you should do it like this, just note that your current "async" implementation does not add any benefits over synchronous one.

Then, because of the same blocking on connectionWaitHandle, you have your issue with aborting the thread. Suppose for example you just start your listener and no client is ever connected. Then client is blocked on connectionWaitHandle and the fact you set _shutdownEvent does not help - main thread will never have a chance to check it.

Your best option to fix it is to use Task based approach:

```
class Listener {
    // we don't use cancellation tokens because AcceptTcpClientAsync does not support them anyway
    private volatile bool _shutdown;
    private TcpListener _listener;

    public async Task Start() {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 10010);
        _listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        _listener.Start();
        while (!_shutdown) {
            TcpClient client = null;
            try {
                client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException) {
                // will be thrown when you stop listener   
            }
            if (client != null) {
                var tcpConnectedLogic = new TcpConnectionLogic(client);
                // start processing on thread pool thread if necessary
                // don't wait for it to finish - you need to accept more connections
                tcpConnectedLogic.StartAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop() {
        _shutdown = true;
        _listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I implement the tcpConnectedLogic.StartAsync()?

Comment: I don't understand why you say the connectionWaitHandle doesn't work.  The code should wait until the wait handle is set - which happens before all the processing on the new thread starts.  So, after the client is received my understanding is that the main thread continues the loop while the previous connection continues in a new thread with the code in my logic layer.

Comment: 1. Just run whatever logic you have there on thread pool thread (Task.Run(YourLogic)). You better run that on separate thread because then you might accept more connections meanwhile. Otherwise you will have to process one client before accepting next one.

Comment: 2. connectionWaitHandle does work - but this way you block your main thread by waiting on that handle, so you accept connections synchronously. Main point in asynchronous accepting connections is that NO thread is blocked by waiting. Plus, the way you do this leads to thread abort problem you have, as described in answer.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the code, but it is not cooperating.  Thanks for the tip, I'll keep trying, but for the time being it is not working.

Comment: I tested my code above before posting and it is working.

Comment: I trust your code works.  That is why I'm spending the time trying to implement it.  Perhaps I can chat with you monday or tuesday?  Adding this paradigm to my solution is not as straight forward as your example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110010/discussion-between-evk-and-adam-heeg).